# Buffer comparison in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm new in Node.js. There aren't Buffer comparison and I should use modules like  [buffertools](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-buffertools) for these feature.

But I see a pretty strange behaviour when I compare Buffer objects in pure Node.

```
> var b1 = new Buffer([170]);
> var b2 = new Buffer([171]);
> b1
<Buffer aa>
> b2
<Buffer ab>
> b1 < b2
false
> b1 > b2
false
> b1 == b2
false
```

and

```
> var b1 = new Buffer([10]);
> var b2 = new Buffer([14]);
> b1
<Buffer 0a>
> b2
<Buffer 0e>
> b1 > b2
false
> b1 < b2
true
> b1 == b2
false
```

What actually happens under the hood?

Comment: How are you declaring `b1` and `b2` in both scenarios?

Comment: Could you provide b1 and b2 definition.

Comment: (1) never ever use `==` in JavaScript except you know what you're doing; instead, always use `===` (2) there are no equivalence tests in JavaScript except for `undefined`, `null`, `true`, `false`, numbers (including `Infinity`, but excluding `NaN`), and strings; nothing else can be meaningfully compared with `===`, bc that is essentially a value *identity* operator. `x === y` means `x` and `y` share the same allocated memory / are the identical same object. `x === y` is always `false` otherwise, hence e.g. `[] === []` is `false`.—Also see my comment to the accepted answer, below.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That's how the comparison operators work on objects:

```
var a = {}, b = {};
a === b; //false
a == b; //false
a > b; //false
a < b; //false

var c = { valueOf : function () { return 0; } };
var d = { valueOf : function () { return 1; } };
c === d; //false
c == d; //false
c > d; //false
c < d; //true
```

### Under the hood

(sort of)

#### Part 1 : Equality

This is the easiest part. Both abstract equality (`==`, [spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)) and strict equality (`===`, [spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6)) check if you're referring to the same object (sort of comparing references). In this case, they are obviously not, so they answer is `false` (`==` spec step 10, `===` spec step 7).

Therefore, in both cases:

```
b1 == b2 //false
b1 === b2 //false
```

#### Part 2: The Comparison strikes back

Here comes the interesting part. Let's look at how the relational operators (`<` and `>`) [are defined](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5). Let's follow the call chain in the two cases.

```
x = b1 //<Buffer aa>
y = b2 //<Buffer ab>

//11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm (http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5)
Let px be the result of calling ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).
Let py be the result of calling ToPrimitive(y, hint Number).

//9.1 ToPrimitive (http://es5.github.com/#x9.1)
InputType is Object, therefore we call the internal [[DefaultValue]] method with hint Number.

//8.12.8 [[DefaultValue]] (hint) http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.8
We try and fetch the object's toString method. If it's defined, call it.
```

And here we've reached the climax: What's a buffer's `toString` method? The answer lies deep inside node.js internals. If you want, [have at it](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/51f128d64b250dfeb128aab5117b5bbcd2cc51b5/lib/buffer.js#L389).  What we can find out trivially is by experimentation:

```
> b1.toString()
'�'
> b2.toString()
'�'
```

okay, that wasn't helpful. You'll notice that in the Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm (what a big fancy name for `<`), there's a step for dealing with strings. It just converts them to their numeric value - the char codes. Let's do that:

```
> b1.toString().charCodeAt(0)
65533
> b2.toString().charCodeAt(0)
65533
```

65533 is an important number. It's the sum of two squares: `142^2 + 213^2`. It also happens to be the Unicode Replacement Character, a character signifying "I have no idea what happened". That's why its hexadecimal equivalent is FFFD.

Obviously, `65533 === 65533`, so:

```
b1 < b2 //is
b1.toString().charCodeAt(0) < b2.toString().charCodeAt(0) //is
65533 < 65533 //false
b1 > b2 //following same logic as above, false
```

And that's that.

#### Dude, what the hell?

Okay, this must've been confusing since my efforts of explanation haven't been well thought through. To recap, here's what happened:

1. You created a buffer. [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum) helped me recreate your test case by doing:

   `var b1 = new Buffer([170]), b2 = new Buffer([171]);`
2. When outputting to console, the values are turned into their hex equivalent (see [Buffer#inspect](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/51f128d64b250dfeb128aab5117b5bbcd2cc51b5/lib/buffer.js#L283)):

   `170..toString(16) === 'aa'`

   `171..toString(16) === 'ab'`
3. However, internally, they represented invalid characters (since it's not hex encoding; again, you're free to delve into the implementation nitty gritty, I won't (oh the irony)). Therefore, when converted to a string, they were represented with the Unicode replacement character.
4. Since they're different objects, any equality operator will return `false`.
5. However, due to the way less-than and greater-than work, they were turned into strings (and then to numbers) for comparison. In light of point #3, that's the same value; therefore, they cannot be less-than or greater-than each other, leading to `false`.

Finally, just to put a smile on your face:

```
b1 <= b2 //true
b1 >= b2 //true
```

Comment: Awesome answer to an interesting question :)

Comment: what you call "abstract equality" (`==`) should really be called "bogus equality" or "well-meant but badly implemented fancy equivalence"; what you call "strict equality" (`===`) is neither about strictness nor equality, rather it checks value identity. Read an in-depth discussion of these issues on https://github.com/loveencounterflow/jseq

Answer (score 10):

There's already an accepted answer but I thought I might still as well chime in with a remark since I don't find the accepted answer particularly clear or helpful. It's even incorrect if only because it answers questions that the OP didn't ask. So let's boil that down:

```
> var b1 = new Buffer([170]);
> var b2 = new Buffer([171]);
> b1 < b2
> b1 > b2
> b1 == b2
```

All that is asked for is: "how do I perform equivalence and less than / greater than comparison (a.k.a. (total) ordering) on buffers".

The answer is:

- either do it manually by stepping through all the  bytes of both buffers and perform a comparison between the corresponding bytes, e.g. `b1[ idx ] === b2[ idx ]`,
- or use `Buffer.compare( b1, b2 )` which gives you one of `-1`, `0`, or `+1`, depending on whether the first buffer would sort before, exactly like, or after the second (sorting a list `d` that contains buffers is then as easy as `d.sort( Buffer.compare )`).

Observe I use `===` in my first example; my frequent comments on this site concerning the abuse of `==` in JavaScript should make it abundantly clear why that is so.