# How to use Node.js to compare text and image file contents for equality?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, fs, jasmine-node

I'm writing a spec using Jasmine Node and I'd like to compare the content of files on disk with the content of files in memory to check that they are equal.

Most of the files are text, but one is an image file (PNG).

How can this can be done?

Comment: Eliot sorry, but this is off-topic for SO, but not for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: @gsamaras Edited, your guidance appreciated, thx

Comment: I got back my close vote and downvote, but I still think that what you ask is too broad, but maybe I am wrong, so good luck!

Answer (score 3):

In node.js you can read data like Buffer, so you can compare data in binary format

```
b1.toString("binary") == b2.toString("binary");
// were b1 and b2 is Buffer
```

For node.js buffer comparison you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790259/buffer-comparison-in-node-js)